How to programmatically get current source location in GDB?
I am trying to get the current breakpoint's source location, preferably as a ("file.c", 15) tuple.
I know about the edit command, but it won't do as I don't want to open a new editor window (my goal is to run a tmux command that will navigate to the breakpoint in an already open editor).
It would be great if there was a way to what the edit does but as text, or just to get the current breakpoint's line and file in a script.
I've successfully set up a Python command, but can't find documentation on how to access the current breakpoint:
import gdb

class GetSourceLocationCommand(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.Command.__init__(self, "foo", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        print("hw")
        breakp = gdb.selected_frame().pc()
        if breakp is None:
            return
        print(breakp) 
        
GetSourceLocationCommand()

This seems to be really simple but I can't find how to do it

From the name GetSourceLocationCommand I would expect it would show the current source location, regardless from the current breakpoint. If you step through the code there would be no breakpoint matching the current position.

You'll have to iterate through all breakopints with gdb.breakpoints(), and then compare which of them contains a BreakpointLocation.address matching gdb.selected_frame().pc(). If you have that, then you can also access BreakpointLocation.source which has what you need.

Thanks to ssbssa I've written an implementation:
import gdb

class GetBpSourceCommand(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.Command.__init__(self, "foo", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        mainPc = gdb.selected_frame().pc()
        for bp in gdb.breakpoints():
            for loc in bp.locations:
                if loc.address == mainPc:
                    return loc.source
        return None 
        
GetBpSourceCommand()

Example return value is ('main.c', 4) which is what I needed
